# Django Update /query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to update a variable in a model, but its not happening. Dont know why?? I've been doing like this before as well and it used to work, but dont why is it not happening ?? any advice.

**my model**

```
class VehicleDetails(models.Model):
    vehicle_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    total_shipments = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    remaining_shipments = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)
```

**What I'm trying to do**

```
        vehicle_details_obj = VehicleDetails.objects.filter(status = 'open').order_by('-time')
        try: 
            vehicle_name = vehicle_details_obj[0].vehicle_name
            remaining_shipments = int(vehicle_details_obj[0].remaining_shipments) - 1
            print remaining_shipments
            vehicle_details_obj[0].remaining_shipments = str(remaining_shipments)
            if remaining_shipments == 0: vehicle_details_obj[0].status = 'close'
            vehicle_details_obj[0].save()
        except : 
            vehicle_name = 'NA'
```

I update the `remaining_shipments` field by subtracting 1 from it and then updating it. I used to update like this before, but its not happening. I've tried `vehicle_details_obj[0].update(remaining_shipments = remaining_shipments)` as well, but its not working. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "its not working"? What is happening instead? Any errors?

Comment: No error. Had there been any error, I wiuld've debbugged it myself. There's nothing happening. I print a statement above and below the `.save()` line, both gets printed, but the update is not happening.

Comment: You will not see any errors because you have an empty `except:` clause which is catching all exceptions. Remove the `try/except` and then run the code.

Comment: I've tried printing the exception, if its going into the except block, doesnt prints any. Removed try/except as well still doesnt show any error.